# How to use findAll method in spring boot with cruderepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My `UserRepository`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<User> findAll(List<Integer> ids);
}
```

Error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property findAll found for type User

Refer - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findAll-java.lang.Iterable-

Can some one tell me how to get list of `User` objects based on List of Id's.

*This is working*

```
@Query(" select new User(id,x,y,z) from User b where b.id in ?1 ")
List<User> findById(List<Integer> id);
```

Comment: Isn't that a working solution? `@Query(" select b from User b where b.id in ?1 ")` seems correct

Comment: @AliDehghani yes, that is working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I would rename the repository to `UserRepository`, because having 2 `User` classes is confusing.

<s>`findAll()`, by definition, is meant to get all the models with no criteria. You should add a method named
`findByIdIn(Collection<Integer> ids)`</s>

Use `List<User> findAll(Iterable<Integer> ids)` or `List<User> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids)`

Comment: Check this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findAll-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: Well that's interesting then, maybe he needs to use Iterable<Integer> instead of List<Integer> then? Or maybe he is mixing the classes (the repository and the entity class, as they have the same name).. But the findByIdIn should work fine.

Comment: 1)List<User> findAll(Iterable<Integer> ids); -> Worked


2)List<User> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids); -> Worked


Please add both in your answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Edited it. (too short...)

Comment: @rinuthomaz Thanks a lot. findAllByIdIn also works for me.